# how to write my terminal in a text file using python

Tags: python

Partial of my code is below. I want to export output of terminal in a text file but I get below error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-c7d647fa741c> in <module>()
     34     text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
     35 
---> 36     text_file.write(data)
     37     #print (data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 150-151: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

```
# data is multi line text
data = ''.join(soup1.findAll('p', text=True))
text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")
text_file.write(data)
# print (data)
```

Comment: Add `# -*- encoding=utf-8 -*-` to the top of your script. You might also need to encode the data you are writing

Comment: `# -*- encoding=utf-8 -*-` helps when you have Unicode in the `.py` file itself and has nothing to do with reading and writing unicode data from and to files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encode your text before you write to the file:

```
text_file.write(data.encode("utf-8"))
```